# Create curved layout for Android Wearable Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I am trying to create a curved Wearable Recycler view similar to the one given in below link: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html

But I don't see curved layout and all the text comes in a single line .
Can anyone help me how to create a curved Wearable Recycler view . The below is the code fragment. Please let me know if something went wrong in the below code:

My Layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.wearable.view.WearableRecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  >
</android.support.wearable.view.WearableRecyclerView>
```

In my fragment I am using the below code for curved layout:

```
InformationAdapter informationAdapter = new InformationAdapter(dataSet, images,MenuActivity.this );<br>
        wearableRecyclerView.setAdapter(informationAdapter); <br>
        wearableRecyclerView.setCenterEdgeItems(true);<br>
        wearableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new CurvedChildLayoutManager(getActivity()));<br>

wearableRecyclerView.setCircularScrollingGestureEnabled(true);
wearableRecyclerView.setBezelWidth(0.5f);
wearableRecyclerView.setScrollDegreesPerScreen(90);
```

My Adapter is as below:

```
public class InformationAdapter extends
        WearableRecyclerView.Adapter<InformationAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomRecyclerAdapter";

    private String[] mDataSet;
    private int[] mImages;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    // Custom Controller used to instruct main activity to update {@link Notification} and/or
    // UI for item selected.

    public static class ViewHolder extends WearableRecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView mTextView;
        private  final ImageView menuImageIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
             menuImageIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_image);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return (String) mTextView.getText(); }
    }


    public InformationAdapter(String[] dataSet,int[] mImages,ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        viewHolder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            //    mController.itemSelected(mDataSet[position]);
                itemClickListener.onItemSelected(mDataSet[position]);
            }
        });

        // Replaces content of view with correct element from data set
        viewHolder.mTextView.setText(mDataSet[position]);
        viewHolder.menuImageIcon.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length;
    }
}
```

Row Item layout for Adapter:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/recycler_row_padding"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_n_white_48dp"
        android:id="@+id/menu_image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="@dimen/recycler_row_text_size"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can any one help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same problem. Changing

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

in WearableRecyclerView worked for me. Hope it helps.